# Animate navigation bar with a flexible height in xcode 11 using Swift

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, uinavigationbar

Any ideas how to create like this animation on iOS using Swift ? Thanks

[image]

Comment: see [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lML5XMLrZEk) youtube tutorial

Comment: It's not a navigation bar. But looks nice

Comment: This is looks like a webview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three ways to achieve this (probably more than three):

1. Create a custom header and listen to your table view Scroll, then update the header based on the offset.
2. Use a third party library like this one:

   - https://material.io/components/ios/catalog/flexible-headers/
3. Follow a tutorial (there are many of them): https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lML5XMLrZEk

Sometimes it is better to do that by yourself, but in this case, I think a framework could help you.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's not the UINavigationBar. You could change nav bar alpha then add custom view to table view or collection view and create animation that you need when scrolling.

Answer (score 0):

Custom Collection view flow layout or ScrollView with UIScrollViewDelegate adjusting the header height when content offset is changing.